# Saving a PHP variable to JSON

Tags: php, json, variables

I have a query that gets some data from a DB and I save that to a PHP variable.

I was wondering how I could pass the PHP variable to a JSON variable?

IE:

```
$content = $row['content']; 

class Foo 
{ 
    public $a = "$content"; 

} 

$obj = new Foo(); 
echo json_encode($obj);
```

Can anyone help me out?

THanks!

Comment: json_encode() is the right function.  What output were you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//assuming  $row['content'] is an array

    class foo{
       public $a;
      public function __construct($content){
           $this->a = $content;
       }
    }
    $content = $row['content'];
    $obj = new foo($content);
    echo json_encode($obj->a);
```

Answer (score 2):

The above should work if you create a constructor for the object, and pass the value in.

e.g.

```
$content = $row['content']; 

class Foo 
{ 
    public $a;

    public function __construct($val) {
       $this->a = $val;
    }

} 

$obj = new Foo($content); 
echo json_encode($obj);
```

Or, as an array:

```
$content = $row['content']; 
$array = array('a' => $content);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
echo json_encode(array('a' => $obj->a));
```

Comment: does `$obj->a` ever equal `$content` in the OP?